# Magento ajax Add to cart Not working

Tags: magento2, ajax

This is my Load more Script, first page Ajax Add to cart, working fine, but if I go to second page, ajax add to cart, is not working

I checked the network tab for the add to cart ajax request, and its not getting called. Hence I added the below code

**`$("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();`** but No luck

```
<script src ="https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/vendor/jquery-ias/dist/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<link src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ravbetsky/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/css/jquery.ias.css"/>
var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  ".test",
    item:       ".products-grid",
    pagination: ".pages-items li",
    next:       ".item a"
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());            // shows a spinner (a.k.a. loader)
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 3})); // shows a trigger after page 3
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'      // override text when no pages left
}));
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    var $items = jQuery(items);
    $items.each(function() {
      var cartBtn = $("button[class='test']"); 
      cartBtn.click(function () {
        console.log("Added....");
      var id = this.id;
      alert(id);
      console.log(id);

});
```

**`For every scroll first product ajax add to cart working fine`**

Comment: Are you getting alerted the id when the products are loaded?

Comment: Yes I am getting alert in id

Comment: where did you add $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();

Comment: I posted an answer of where i would have put the code in your module.

Comment: JS seems  a bit messy also missinga  lot of closing backets is this what you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing that code within rendered?

**e.g**

```
<script>
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
  $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
  var $items = jQuery(items);
  $items.each(function() {
    var cartBtn = $("button[class='test']"); 
    cartBtn.click(function () {
      console.log("Added....");
      var id = this.id;
      alert(id);
      console.log(id);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Full code working on my demo store:

```
<link src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ravbetsky/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/css/jquery.ias.css"/>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

var IASCallbacks=function(a){return this.list=[],this.fireStack=[],this.isFiring=!1,this.isDisabled=!1,this.Deferred=a.Deferred,this.fire=function(a){var b=a[0],c=a[1],d=a[2];this.isFiring=!0;for(var e=0,f=this.list.length;f>e;e++)if(void 0!=this.list[e]&&!1===this.list[e].fn.apply(b,d)){c.reject();break}this.isFiring=!1,c.resolve(),this.fireStack.length&&this.fire(this.fireStack.shift())},this.inList=function(a,b){b=b||0;for(var c=b,d=this.list.length;d>c;c++)if(this.list[c].fn===a||a.guid&&this.list[c].fn.guid&&a.guid===this.list[c].fn.guid)return c;return-1},this};IASCallbacks.prototype={add:function(a,b){var c={fn:a,priority:b};b=b||0;for(var d=0,e=this.list.length;e>d;d++)if(b>this.list[d].priority)return this.list.splice(d,0,c),this;return this.list.push(c),this},remove:function(a){for(var b=0;(b=this.inList(a,b))>-1;)this.list.splice(b,1);return this},has:function(a){return this.inList(a)>-1},fireWith:function(a,b){var c=this.Deferred();return this.isDisabled?c.reject():(b=b||[],b=[a,c,b.slice?b.slice():b],this.isFiring?this.fireStack.push(b):this.fire(b),c)},disable:function(){this.isDisabled=!0},enable:function(){this.isDisabled=!1}},function(a){"use strict";var b=-1,c=function(c,d){return this.itemsContainerSelector=d.container,this.itemSelector=d.item,this.nextSelector=d.next,this.paginationSelector=d.pagination,this.$scrollContainer=c,this.$container=window===c.get(0)?a(document):c,this.defaultDelay=d.delay,this.negativeMargin=d.negativeMargin,this.nextUrl=null,this.isBound=!1,this.isPaused=!1,this.isInitialized=!1,this.jsXhr=!1,this.listeners={next:new IASCallbacks(a),load:new IASCallbacks(a),loaded:new IASCallbacks(a),render:new IASCallbacks(a),rendered:new IASCallbacks(a),scroll:new IASCallbacks(a),noneLeft:new IASCallbacks(a),ready:new IASCallbacks(a)},this.extensions=[],this.scrollHandler=function(){if(this.isBound&&!this.isPaused){var a=this.getCurrentScrollOffset(this.$scrollContainer),c=this.getScrollThreshold();b!=c&&(this.fire("scroll",[a,c]),a>=c&&this.next())}},this.getItemsContainer=function(){return a(this.itemsContainerSelector,this.$container)},this.getLastItem=function(){return a(this.itemSelector,this.getItemsContainer().get(0)).last()},this.getFirstItem=function(){return a(this.itemSelector,this.getItemsContainer().get(0)).first()},this.getScrollThreshold=function(a){var c;return a=a||this.negativeMargin,a=a>=0?-1*a:a,c=this.getLastItem(),0===c.length?b:c.offset().top+c.height()+a},this.getCurrentScrollOffset=function(a){var b=0,c=a.height();return b=window===a.get(0)?a.scrollTop():a.offset().top,(-1!=navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone")||-1!=navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod"))&&(c+=80),b+c},this.getNextUrl=function(b){return b=b||this.$container,a(this.nextSelector,b).last().attr("href")},this.load=function(b,c,d){var e,f,g=this,h=[],i=+new Date;d=d||this.defaultDelay;var j={url:b};return g.fire("load",[j]),this.jsXhr=a.get(j.url,null,a.proxy(function(b){e=a(this.itemsContainerSelector,b).eq(0),0===e.length&&(e=a(b).filter(this.itemsContainerSelector).eq(0)),e&&e.find(this.itemSelector).each(function(){h.push(this)}),g.fire("loaded",[b,h]),c&&(f=+new Date-i,d>f?setTimeout(function(){c.call(g,b,h)},d-f):c.call(g,b,h))},g),"html"),this.jsXhr},this.render=function(b,c){var d=this,e=this.getLastItem(),f=0,g=this.fire("render",[b]);g.done(function(){a(b).hide(),e.after(b),a(b).fadeIn(400,function(){++f<b.length||(d.fire("rendered",[b]),c&&c())})}),g.fail(function(){c&&c()})},this.hidePagination=function(){this.paginationSelector&&a(this.paginationSelector,this.$container).hide()},this.restorePagination=function(){this.paginationSelector&&a(this.paginationSelector,this.$container).show()},this.throttle=function(b,c){var d,e,f=0;return d=function(){function a(){f=+new Date,b.apply(d,g)}var d=this,g=arguments,h=+new Date-f;e?clearTimeout(e):a(),h>c?a():e=setTimeout(a,c)},a.guid&&(d.guid=b.guid=b.guid||a.guid++),d},this.fire=function(a,b){return this.listeners[a].fireWith(this,b)},this.pause=function(){this.isPaused=!0},this.resume=function(){this.isPaused=!1},this};c.prototype.initialize=function(){if(this.isInitialized)return!1;var a=!!("onscroll"in this.$scrollContainer.get(0)),b=this.getCurrentScrollOffset(this.$scrollContainer),c=this.getScrollThreshold();return a?(this.hidePagination(),this.bind(),this.nextUrl=this.getNextUrl(),b>=c?(this.next(),this.one("rendered",function(){this.isInitialized=!0,this.fire("ready")})):(this.isInitialized=!0,this.fire("ready")),this):!1},c.prototype.reinitialize=function(){this.isInitialized=!1,this.unbind(),this.initialize()},c.prototype.bind=function(){if(!this.isBound){this.$scrollContainer.on("scroll",a.proxy(this.throttle(this.scrollHandler,150),this));for(var b=0,c=this.extensions.length;c>b;b++)this.extensions[b].bind(this);this.isBound=!0,this.resume()}},c.prototype.unbind=function(){if(this.isBound){this.$scrollContainer.off("scroll",this.scrollHandler);for(var a=0,b=this.extensions.length;b>a;a++)"undefined"!=typeof this.extensions[a].unbind&&this.extensions[a].unbind(this);this.isBound=!1}},c.prototype.destroy=function(){try{this.jsXhr.abort()}catch(a){}this.unbind(),this.$scrollContainer.data("ias",null)},c.prototype.on=function(b,c,d){if("undefined"==typeof this.listeners[b])throw new Error('There is no event called "'+b+'"');return d=d||0,this.listeners[b].add(a.proxy(c,this),d),this},c.prototype.one=function(a,b){var c=this,d=function(){c.off(a,b),c.off(a,d)};return this.on(a,b),this.on(a,d),this},c.prototype.off=function(a,b){if("undefined"==typeof this.listeners[a])throw new Error('There is no event called "'+a+'"');return this.listeners[a].remove(b),this},c.prototype.next=function(){var a=this.nextUrl,b=this;if(this.pause(),!a)return this.fire("noneLeft",[this.getLastItem()]),this.listeners.noneLeft.disable(),b.resume(),!1;var c=this.fire("next",[a]);return c.done(function(){b.load(a,function(a,c){b.render(c,function(){b.nextUrl=b.getNextUrl(a),b.resume()})})}),c.fail(function(){b.resume()}),!0},c.prototype.extension=function(a){if("undefined"==typeof a.bind)throw new Error('Extension doesn\'t have required method "bind"');return"undefined"!=typeof a.initialize&&a.initialize(this),this.extensions.push(a),this.isBound&&this.reinitialize(),this},a.ias=function(b){var c=a(window);return c.ias.apply(c,arguments)},a.fn.ias=function(b){var d=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),e=this;return this.each(function(){var f=a(this),g=f.data("ias"),h=a.extend({},a.fn.ias.defaults,f.data(),"object"==typeof b&&b);if(g||(f.data("ias",g=new c(f,h)),a(document).ready(a.proxy(g.initialize,g))),"string"==typeof b){if("function"!=typeof g[b])throw new Error('There is no method called "'+b+'"');d.shift(),g[b].apply(g,d)}e=g}),e},a.fn.ias.defaults={item:".item",container:".listing",next:".next",pagination:!1,delay:600,negativeMargin:10}}(jQuery);var IASHistoryExtension=function(a){return a=jQuery.extend({},this.defaults,a),this.ias=null,this.prevSelector=a.prev,this.prevUrl=null,this.listeners={prev:new IASCallbacks(jQuery)},this.onPageChange=function(a,b,c){if(window.history&&window.history.replaceState){var d=history.state;history.replaceState(d,document.title,c)}},this.onScroll=function(a,b){var c=this.getScrollThresholdFirstItem();this.prevUrl&&(a-=this.ias.$scrollContainer.height(),c>=a&&this.prev())},this.onReady=function(){var a=this.ias.getCurrentScrollOffset(this.ias.$scrollContainer),b=this.getScrollThresholdFirstItem();a-=this.ias.$scrollContainer.height(),b>=a&&this.prev()},this.getPrevUrl=function(a){return a||(a=this.ias.$container),jQuery(this.prevSelector,a).last().attr("href")},this.getScrollThresholdFirstItem=function(){var a;return a=this.ias.getFirstItem(),0===a.length?-1:a.offset().top},this.renderBefore=function(a,b){var c=this.ias,d=c.getFirstItem(),e=0;c.fire("render",[a]),jQuery(a).hide(),d.before(a),jQuery(a).fadeIn(400,function(){++e<a.length||(c.fire("rendered",[a]),b&&b())})},this};IASHistoryExtension.prototype.initialize=function(a){var b=this;this.ias=a,jQuery.extend(a.listeners,this.listeners),a.prev=function(){return b.prev()},this.prevUrl=this.getPrevUrl()},IASHistoryExtension.prototype.bind=function(a){a.on("pageChange",jQuery.proxy(this.onPageChange,this)),a.on("scroll",jQuery.proxy(this.onScroll,this)),a.on("ready",jQuery.proxy(this.onReady,this))},IASHistoryExtension.prototype.unbind=function(a){a.off("pageChange",this.onPageChange),a.off("scroll",this.onScroll),a.off("ready",this.onReady)},IASHistoryExtension.prototype.prev=function(){var a=this.prevUrl,b=this,c=this.ias;if(!a)return!1;c.pause();var d=c.fire("prev",[a]);return d.done(function(){c.load(a,function(a,d){b.renderBefore(d,function(){b.prevUrl=b.getPrevUrl(a),c.resume(),b.prevUrl&&b.prev()})})}),d.fail(function(){c.resume()}),!0},IASHistoryExtension.prototype.defaults={prev:".prev"};var IASNoneLeftExtension=function(a){return a=jQuery.extend({},this.defaults,a),this.ias=null,this.uid=(new Date).getTime(),this.html=a.html.replace("{text}",a.text),this.showNoneLeft=function(){var a=jQuery(this.html).attr("id","ias_noneleft_"+this.uid),b=this.ias.getLastItem();b.after(a),a.fadeIn()},this};IASNoneLeftExtension.prototype.bind=function(a){this.ias=a,a.on("noneLeft",jQuery.proxy(this.showNoneLeft,this))},IASNoneLeftExtension.prototype.unbind=function(a){a.off("noneLeft",this.showNoneLeft)},IASNoneLeftExtension.prototype.defaults={text:"You reached the end.",html:'<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align: center;">{text}</div>'};var IASPagingExtension=function(){return this.ias=null,this.pagebreaks=[[0,document.location.toString()]],this.lastPageNum=1,this.enabled=!0,this.listeners={pageChange:new IASCallbacks(jQuery)},this.onScroll=function(a,b){if(this.enabled){var c,d=this.ias,e=this.getCurrentPageNum(a),f=this.getCurrentPagebreak(a);this.lastPageNum!==e&&(c=f[1],d.fire("pageChange",[e,a,c])),this.lastPageNum=e}},this.onNext=function(a){var b=this.ias.getCurrentScrollOffset(this.ias.$scrollContainer);this.pagebreaks.push([b,a]);var c=this.getCurrentPageNum(b)+1;this.ias.fire("pageChange",[c,b,a]),this.lastPageNum=c},this.onPrev=function(a){var b=this,c=b.ias,d=c.getCurrentScrollOffset(c.$scrollContainer),e=d-c.$scrollContainer.height(),f=c.getFirstItem();this.enabled=!1,this.pagebreaks.unshift([0,a]),c.one("rendered",function(){for(var d=1,g=b.pagebreaks.length;g>d;d++)b.pagebreaks[d][0]=b.pagebreaks[d][0]+f.offset().top;var h=b.getCurrentPageNum(e)+1;c.fire("pageChange",[h,e,a]),b.lastPageNum=h,b.enabled=!0})},this};IASPagingExtension.prototype.initialize=function(a){this.ias=a,jQuery.extend(a.listeners,this.listeners)},IASPagingExtension.prototype.bind=function(a){try{a.on("prev",jQuery.proxy(this.onPrev,this),this.priority)}catch(b){}a.on("next",jQuery.proxy(this.onNext,this),this.priority),a.on("scroll",jQuery.proxy(this.onScroll,this),this.priority)},IASPagingExtension.prototype.unbind=function(a){try{a.off("prev",this.onPrev)}catch(b){}a.off("next",this.onNext),a.off("scroll",this.onScroll)},IASPagingExtension.prototype.getCurrentPageNum=function(a){for(var b=this.pagebreaks.length-1;b>0;b--)if(a>this.pagebreaks[b][0])return b+1;return 1},IASPagingExtension.prototype.getCurrentPagebreak=function(a){for(var b=this.pagebreaks.length-1;b>=0;b--)if(a>this.pagebreaks[b][0])return this.pagebreaks[b];return null},IASPagingExtension.prototype.priority=500;var IASSpinnerExtension=function(a){return a=jQuery.extend({},this.defaults,a),this.ias=null,this.uid=(new Date).getTime(),this.src=a.src,this.html=a.html.replace("{src}",this.src),this.showSpinner=function(){var a=this.getSpinner()||this.createSpinner(),b=this.ias.getLastItem();b.after(a),a.fadeIn()},this.showSpinnerBefore=function(){var a=this.getSpinner()||this.createSpinner(),b=this.ias.getFirstItem();b.before(a),a.fadeIn()},this.removeSpinner=function(){this.hasSpinner()&&this.getSpinner().remove()},this.getSpinner=function(){var a=jQuery("#ias_spinner_"+this.uid);return a.length>0?a:!1},this.hasSpinner=function(){var a=jQuery("#ias_spinner_"+this.uid);return a.length>0},this.createSpinner=function(){var a=jQuery(this.html).attr("id","ias_spinner_"+this.uid);return a.hide(),a},this};IASSpinnerExtension.prototype.bind=function(a){this.ias=a,a.on("next",jQuery.proxy(this.showSpinner,this)),a.on("render",jQuery.proxy(this.removeSpinner,this));try{a.on("prev",jQuery.proxy(this.showSpinnerBefore,this))}catch(b){}},IASSpinnerExtension.prototype.unbind=function(a){a.off("next",this.showSpinner),a.off("render",this.removeSpinner);try{a.off("prev",this.showSpinnerBefore)}catch(b){}},IASSpinnerExtension.prototype.defaults={src:"data:image/gif;base64,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",html:'<div class="ias-spinner" style="text-align: center;"><img src="{src}"/></div>'};var IASTriggerExtension=function(a){return a=jQuery.extend({},this.defaults,a),this.ias=null,this.html=a.html.replace("{text}",a.text),this.htmlPrev=a.htmlPrev.replace("{text}",a.textPrev),this.enabled=!0,this.count=0,this.offset=a.offset,this.$triggerNext=null,this.$triggerPrev=null,this.showTriggerNext=function(){if(!this.enabled)return!0;if(!1===this.offset||++this.count<this.offset)return!0;var a=this.$triggerNext||(this.$triggerNext=this.createTrigger(this.next,this.html)),b=this.ias.getLastItem();return b.after(a),a.fadeIn(),!1},this.showTriggerPrev=function(){if(!this.enabled)return!0;var a=this.$triggerPrev||(this.$triggerPrev=this.createTrigger(this.prev,this.htmlPrev)),b=this.ias.getFirstItem();return b.before(a),a.fadeIn(),!1},this.onRendered=function(){this.enabled=!0},this.createTrigger=function(a,b){var c,d=(new Date).getTime();return b=b||this.html,c=jQuery(b).attr("id","ias_trigger_"+d),c.hide(),c.on("click",jQuery.proxy(a,this)),c},this};IASTriggerExtension.prototype.bind=function(a){this.ias=a,a.on("next",jQuery.proxy(this.showTriggerNext,this),this.priority),a.on("rendered",jQuery.proxy(this.onRendered,this),this.priority);try{a.on("prev",jQuery.proxy(this.showTriggerPrev,this),this.priority)}catch(b){}},IASTriggerExtension.prototype.unbind=function(a){a.off("next",this.showTriggerNext),a.off("rendered",this.onRendered);try{a.off("prev",this.showTriggerPrev)}catch(b){}},IASTriggerExtension.prototype.next=function(){this.enabled=!1,this.ias.pause(),this.$triggerNext&&(this.$triggerNext.remove(),this.$triggerNext=null),this.ias.next()},IASTriggerExtension.prototype.prev=function(){this.enabled=!1,this.ias.pause(),this.$triggerPrev&&(this.$triggerPrev.remove(),this.$triggerPrev=null),this.ias.prev()},IASTriggerExtension.prototype.defaults={text:"Load more items",html:'<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-next" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',textPrev:"Load previous items",htmlPrev:'<div class="ias-trigger ias-trigger-prev" style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><a>{text}</a></div>',offset:0},IASTriggerExtension.prototype.priority=1e3;

var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  ".main",
    item:       ".products-grid",
    pagination: ".pages-items li",
    next:       ".item a"
});
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());            // shows a spinner (a.k.a. loader)
ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 3})); // shows a trigger after page 3
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'      // override text when no pages left
}));
ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
    var $items = jQuery(items);
    $items.each(function() {
      var cartBtn = $("button[class='test']"); 
      cartBtn.click(function () {
        console.log("Added....");
      });
      var id = this.id;
      alert(id);
      console.log(id);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Still same no request is going

Comment: Have you any console errors?

Comment: No error asusual first product is going not others

Comment: Have the add to cart form got the data-role="tocart-form"?

Comment: I am going to give this a go on a demo store is that all the code you need for it to work?

Comment: check my full code i updated my list.phtml

Comment: I had to add all require js and that and just pasted the js directly in so a bit messy but this does actually work for me here also.

Comment: Like when i say work i mean it worked ajax add to cart as you said only worked on first page of products all ajax loaded ones caused a page redirect. After adding that line of code in the newly loaded products now add to cart with ajax fine.

Comment: after scroll second page first produt is working not all

Comment: Still? There must be another issue somewhere with your cart form being different from normal. I didnt use your whole list.phtml as it was very custom .

Comment: Okay i use custom submit ajax but i can't able to post all data

Comment: Not sure if this may help but does the custom ajax use x magento init?

Comment: try instead of my code  $('.products').trigger('contentUpdated');

Comment: Then maybe need to move the x-magento-init within products div or change the div that your script is in so these scripts can be run again after the ajax.

Comment: Other than that i think we need to know more about how your custom ajax add to cart works to be able to fix.

Comment: For add to cart i am using default only i am using

Comment: Ok strange... i have it working another way now maybe try that?

Comment: With out this code also it working $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();

Comment: Im unsure what you mean? what works without that code?

Comment: First product adding to the cart without that also

Comment: So when you add that no products add to cart with ajax and all instead reload page?

Comment: Not all reload no ajax request is going

Comment: I would maybe try a default list.phtml see if it works there then work backwards putting features back until you see what breaks it.

Comment: It's hard for me to know how to fix without playing with it myself but everytime i try it works for me so hard to know what is different here.

Comment: @Kothari Any luck with that ?

Comment: No luck it's still same onle

Comment: What with default list.phtml

Comment: default list.phtml also same

Comment: Did you get this going in the end?